# Reference for Sobolev estimate on bounded domain with a boundary term on the right side.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Could someone point me to a reference for the proof of the following Sobolev estimate?

$$
\| u\|_{ L^{2d/(d-2)}(\Omega)} \leqslant C\left(\| f \|_{L^{2 d /(d+2)}(\Omega)}+\|g\|_{\partial \Omega}\right)
$$
for all $u \in W^{2,2 d /(d+2)}(\Omega)$ such that $\Delta u=f$ and $g=u$ on $\partial \Omega$, and $d>2$ and $\Omega$ is a smooth domain of $\mathbf{R}^d$.
Thanks in advance to anyone who could offer help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You need to specify the norm of $g$ on $\partial \Omega$ as well.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Here, the norm $\|g\|_{\partial \Omega}$ could be $\|\|_{W^{(3d-2)/2d}(\partial \Omega)}$ or more simply $\|\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}$. The most important for me is to follow the proof of this, if there exists in the literature of course, thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted on Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446390